# How to disable font Arial in Opera?

Tags: css, linux, browser, opera, xorg

After upgrade to Opera 10.60 on my Gentoo Linux it stopped reading fonts.conf all of a sudden and now I am not happy with how Arial bold looks in non-Latin letters. Particularly bold cyrillic "**м**" letter looks almost as black square when Arial is used.
I want to tell opera not to use Arial at all, there are plenty of replacements: Liberation fonts, Droid, etc. I found stylesheets, but not sure how to write statement which prescribes not to use **Arial** in web pages.
I know that there is "**not**" selector in CSS v3, but could not make a valid statement out of it.
Anyone mastered negative statements in CSS?

Comment: CSS is considered programming-related.

Comment: @ChrisW, but this question seems specifically related to a problem in *a piece of software* rather than an issue with css in general.

Comment: @ricebowl Whatever his motive for asking the question, the object is programming-related: I think that developers are more likely than superusers to be able to answer a question about writing a CSS rule.

Comment: @ChrisW, true, but developers are possibly more likely to opt for a css rule rather than finding a relevant tick box somewhere in the program's option dialogues. I think the question constitutes an edge-case between the remit of SU and SO, which makes it valuable in itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to use Opera's config options:

```
opera:config#UserPrefs|LocalCSSFile
```

to define a style rule. While my approach isn't a *negative statement* it should achieve the same result:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Arial";
src: url(path/to/replacement/font.ttf); /* or local(path/to/replacement/font.ttf); */
}
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to force Opera to use your `user.css` file for Arial fonts, or not, but it might work. And it's the best I could think of at the time...good luck! =)

---

**Edited following comments:**

> This seems reasonable but it did not work. May be it has to be used with some element definitions. - temujin.ya.ru

and the response, from ChrisW:

> @temujin.ya.ru See whether it works when used with a stylesheet that specifies Arial explicitly. If so then the problem is with stylesheets that specify Arial implicitly, e.g. by specifying "sans-serif". Also I wonder whether there are other/similar font names e.g. "Arial Cyr", "Arial Cyrillic", etc. – ChrisW

If the problem is related to implied fonts (`font-family: sans-serif;` for example) then the above could be added to, with the following:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "sans-serif";
src: url(path/to/replacement/font.ttf); /* or local(path/to/replacement/font.ttf); */
}
```

But this approach would become unwieldy very, very quickly.

An alternative, and possibly better, approach is:

[in Opera] Tools > Preferences > Advanced > Content > Style Options > Presentation Modes

And configure the options available there, which allows you to specify whether pages render under 'author' (author of the web-site) or 'user' (your own) css modes. You can limit this to 'page fonts and colours,' or 'My fonts and colours.'

Though I'm not sure how good, or bad, this alternative might be.

Comment: This seems reasonable but it did not work. May be it has to be used with some element definitions.

Comment: @temujin.ya.ru See whether it works when used with a stylesheet that specifies Arial explicitly. If so then the problem is with stylesheets that specify Arial implicitly, e.g. by specifying "sans-serif". Also I wonder whether there are [other/similar font names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial#Arial_variants) e.g. "Arial Cyr", "Arial Cyrillic", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just symlink Arial to Liberation Sans in your filesystem.

Comment: To bad you can't do this just for opera though